# How to separate my inputs?

Tags: html, css

So I have four inputs and a button. I tried editing them with CSS but I can't seem to get them to separate. They are all together. No matter what numbers I try to change. Here's my code for both files. Sorry if I get something totally wrong i'm a noob.

```css
nav ul input{
 margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
 position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 height: 50px;
 width: 300px;
 background-color: transparent;
 color: black;
 border: solid;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}

#signInBtn{
 margin: 0px;
 position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 height: 50px;
 width: 300px;
 background-color: transparent;
 color: black;
 border: solid;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>NAME</title> 
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Tamma" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

 </html>

<header>
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <?php 
    echo "<form action='includes/signup.inc.php' method='POST'> 
     <input id='nameInput' type='text' name='first' placeholder='Firstname'>
     <input id='lstInput' type='text' name='last' placeholder='Lastname'>
     <input id='usrInput' type='text' name='uid' placeholder='Username'>
     <input id='pwdInput' type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'>
     <button id='signInBtn' type='submit'>Sign Up</button>
    </form>";
   ?>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `button,input {display:block}` and the `ul` needs min. of one `li`

Answer (score 0):

In your css your are using position absolute for all the input. That's why all input come all together.

```
nav ul input {
   position: relative;
   display: block;
}

#signInBtn {
  position: relative;
}
```

just change it to something position relative or what suitable for you.

Comment: When I change position to something else it ends up not centering correctly. I want the inputs to be in a container and no matter how much space is in between them the container will stay in the center.

Comment: add display block in that selector

Comment: Check my answer again I just edit that. And Now your input come in step by step

Answer (score 0):

> You are using  position absolute, causing the overlap issue
>   and also you having wrong closing tag so I corrected your code, Please see demo below and tell me if you need anything else.

```css
.wrapper {
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

    .input_block {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

   input {
    padding: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        color: black;
        border: solid;
        font-size: 15px;
    }


    #signInBtn {
        padding: 20px
        width: 200px;
        color: black;
        border: solid;
        font-size: 30px;
    }

    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: black;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>NAME</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo+Tamma" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <form action='includes/signup.inc.php' method='POST'>
            <div class="input_block">
                <input id='nameInput' type='text' name='first' placeholder='Firstname'>
            </div>

            <div class="input_block">
                <input id='lstInput' type='text' name='last' placeholder='Lastname'>
            </div>

            <div class="input_block">
                <input id='usrInput' type='text' name='uid' placeholder='Username'>
            </div>

            <div class="input_block">
                <input id='pwdInput' type='password' name='pwd' placeholder='Password'>
            </div>

            <div class="input_block">
                <button id='signInBtn' type='submit'>Sign Up</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This works* and is a lot cleaner than my original code.

Comment: *Now how would I position everything in the center in a line from top to bottom?

Comment: I did add <br> in the html code so they are in a line now.

Comment: Well I tried multiple things like position and stuff but can't re position the inputs.

Comment: @InfiSnyp I have updated my code as per your need, please check now..

**margin: 0 auto;** it makes auto margin to right left

Answer (score 0):

```
nav ul input{
/* delete position */
/* add */
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
float: none;
}

/* do the same*/
#signInBtn{
/* delete position */
/* add */d
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
float: none;
}
```

!you don't have to keep the margin 0 and float: none but i think its a good start before figureing out where you want everything